# Can a partition size be changed between cloning and restoring the clone?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, backup, clone, clonezilla

I need to do a full backup of a boot partition of Windows 7.  I want to be able to restore it if needed.

My understanding is that the only way to do this is to clone the partition *byte-for-byte* using something like Clonezilla.  (If I'm in error, please correct me.)

***Question:***

Can I reduce the size of the partition before cloning (in order to minimize the size of the clone image), then increase the size of the partition after the making the clone, and then decrease the partition to the smaller size if the clone ever needs to be restored?  Will that work?

Comment: You can copy as much or as little of a drive or partition as you want using most tools

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks.  My premise might be incorrect.  I thought that in order to backup (and restore) a bootable Windows partition (that can survive a format), you had to perform a *byte-by-byte* clone.  Am I wrong?  I hope so.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard- You need only need the boot partition and the OS partition.  Its up to you to verify the files are within the sectors you specify when you perform the sector-by-sector copy of a particular copy.  You don't have to copy the entire partition or the free space to make the drive bootable.

Answer (score 1):

A byte-for-byte clone as you put it is quite inefficient and Clonezilla by default will not attempt to do such a thing.  Instead it will attempt to copy just the files and data that was listed as being used on the hard drive to the backup medium to keep the backup small.

The only reason to reduce the size of the partition before starting the clone/backup is to ensure that you can restore the image on a smaller disk/partition.  In other words, if your disk is 2TB large and you make a backup of it, you can only restore the backup to other 2TB or larger disks/partitions.  Do keep in mind that, (at the time of this writing), if your 2TB image has only used up say 20GB worth of data, it will still require a 2TB or larger disk/partition to restore to; even though the backup/restored size was 20GB.

Comment: Thanks Blerg!  I think my premise was incorrect.  Tell me if I now understand correctly: To clone a Windows 7 boot drive (using a Clonezilla Live CD) that is 2GB with 100GB of data (1.9GB empty), all you need is a destination media (USB stick, microSD card, hard drive, etc.) with 100GB of free space.  When restoring the clone, all you need is any partition on any drive of 2GB or larger.  Is that all correct?

Comment: Your destination media will need to have enough space to contain everything when backing up.  Clonezilla has an option to compress the backup, so you might get away with something smaller.  For the restoration, you'll need something that is about the size of disk that you backed up.  Clonezilla will NOT restore to a disk that is smaller than the image, even if there was empty space on the drive when the backup was taken.  It's efficient, but a little bit flawed.

Comment: *"...need to have enough space to contain everything..."* Including the empty space within the partition being backed up?  *"...will not restore to a disk that is smaller..."* But will restore to a disk that is larger, correct?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: actually, there are several free programs that will restore to a smaller drive.  See [How can a partial image backup or restore be performed?](http://superuser.com/a/866999/364367).

Comment: Yes, including the empty space.  (If you shrink down the partition first, then you can restore it to smaller locations, but you'll need to resize everything manually.)  It will always restore to a larger disk, but you'll still need to resize the partitions manually after it's done.

Comment: Thanks.  You mentioned "need to resize" twice.  Is the "need" only if you want the partitions to be the same size as before?  IOW, if you don't need the partitions to be the same size as before is there any "need to resize" anything after a restore?

Comment: The reason I said to resize twice was to ensure that you used up all of the unallocated space after restoring the image.  Clonezilla currently does not do this.  So basically what you're doing is shrinking the volume so that you can restore almost anywhere.  Then after you restore the volume you expand it to use up the unallocated space.  If you're just going to use the same disk to restore to, then you don't technically need to do any resizing at all.

Comment: I think my tired brain comprehending what you are saying. ;)  Let's use a concrete example: If you have a 1TB partition with 200GB of data, and you shrink it to 500GB before cloning, then the clone file will be about 200GB and can be restored onto any partition of 500GB or larger.  No resizing needed unless you want that partition to be 1TB again.  Is that all correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard - Copying the empty space is most often a optional flag in most programs.  As indicate before, CloneZilla is a horrible tool, to clone a Windows disk AND migrate the image to a smaller destination

Comment: @Ramhound I wouldn't say horrible.  From what I can tell, it's the tools that it uses that force you to have proper sizes when restoring disks/partitions.  Clonezilla is just a UI that then calls the other programs to do the work.

Comment: @Blerg - I say horrible because its one dimensional.  It scans your HDD and creates a image, it has nearly no features targeted, to restore that image to a system that will run Windows.  While not complicated restoring a HDD image to a smaller disk then the original source, that will boot Windows, is not trivial.  So there are better tools, both free and paid, other then Clonezilla :$

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft came up with `DISM` that solves this issue entirely... DISM doesn't care about partition size but, obviously, *you* must ensure the backed up data will fit onto the smaller disk - i.e. Don't knowingly try to put 500GB worth of `C:` onto a new 250GB disk.

`DISM` is available through the [WAIK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5753) (`Windows Automated Installation Kit`) kit and  you can create bootable media so you can begin using such tools as DISM and DISKPART.

`DISM` captures only the files/folders in use and doesn't have any knowledge of the partition structure used.

`DISM` creates a `.wim` file that is essentially a compressed file but it retains all the files. folders and attributes/permissions on the original install. As an aside: 7-Zip now has the ability to open `.wim` files so, in an emergency, you can easily extract files/folders from a different computer.

When using DISM to restore the image you must pre-create the partitions you require (using `DISKPART` to create (a basic example) the system reserved partition and then the main `C:` partition) and then you can put the WIM file into your new `C:`. It is then recommended you then use the `BCDBoot` tool to copy the Windows boot files to the boot partition (`System Reserved`) which will allow your Windows installation to boot.