# How do I move my current Windows from an ssd to a bigger ssd?

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot

So for months, I have been struggling to live with a 128 GB SSD. The available space of the drive is getting smaller and I had to uninstall some programs over time.  I currently have this SSD as my C drive and a 2TB HDD as my second drive where I try to save everything less important.

I am planning on getting a 250GB or even 500 GB SSD. I then would like to move my current Windows 10 image over to the bigger SSD and use the old one as a dual boot drive for Ubuntu.

Is this feasible? And if, how would one proceed in doing this?

Comment: Create an image of the SSD using your favorite program, apply the image to the new SSD, then verify the new SSD will successfully boot the OS and extend the partition size from within the OS.

Comment: Here are some other duplicate candiates [here](https://superuser.com/questions/750847/can-a-system-image-be-restored-to-a-drive-with-a-different-storage-capacity) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/32164/what-utility-can-move-my-windows-boot-partition-over-to-another-hard-drive/37950?s=10|0.0000#37950)

Answer (score 0):

Use Clonezilla live to clone SSD. Then use Gparted live to change partitions to full new disk size. Then let Windows check and mark partitions as clean.

Works for me, but no guaranties - Clonezilla and Gparted are not commercial software. Your scenario with new clean SSD is easy, but unplug your 2GB hdd, just in case.

Also, some SSDs have migration software bundled with it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, many third party partition tools can help you clone OS. After clone, i suggest you disconnect the source disk, connect the target drive internally to motherboard and see whether it is bootable.