# Is it possible to move win10 installation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd

I have my win10 and various apps installed on my HDD. And I have a new SSD. Is there a way to safely move win10 to the SSD? Or the only way is to install it again?

Comment: Do you want to move just Windows, or are you planning to move everything from the HDD to the SSD?

Comment: there are already tons of results on Google: [How do I move my current Windows from an ssd to a bigger ssd?](https://superuser.com/q/1342946/241386), https://windowsreport.com/move-windows-10-ssd/, https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-move-windows-10-to-an-ssd/...

Comment: You can use the clone tool to realize this. You can refer to: https://superuser.com/questions/99211/free-way-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd

Answer (score 1):

You can using 'disk cloning' software, such as the free and open source [Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/) which I use daily, or many other apps including commercial products, to duplicate what's on your HDD onto the SSD, without a reinstallation of Windows and all its apps. That will erase the SSD.

However, just copying, either by a 'copy' command in a command prompt window, or by drag-and-drop in File Explorer, will not work. Microsoft goes out of its way to prevent folks from copying Windows and Windows programs without buying it, and that's an unfortunate side effect.

Comment: is cloned windows going to work properly? I've heard about this kind of software, but never heard if people use it to move their OS

Comment: I cloned the OS from a hard disk to an SSD a month or so ago using Macrium Reflect. Usually it "just works" but you might need to do a boot repair using the recovery tools from a Windows install disk.

Comment: Yes, it will work.